# Interpretation of hypothesis testing

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, interpretation

I have the following sample. Now I have to test: 
$$H_0\!:\mu=60,\!000
\quad \text{Vs.}\quad
H_a\!:\mu>60,\!000$$

I have computed it in `R Software` But I do not understand the result.

```
 Price  <- c(60,250,400,550,517,380,425,280,389,559)
 Number <- c(3,3,4,5,4,3,6,3,4,5)
 data   <- data.frame(Price, Number)
 price  <- data$Price  #$
 num    <- data$Number

 # test statistic
 xbar   <- mean(price)
 mu0    <- 60000
 s      <- sd(price)
 n      <- length(price)
 t      <- (xbar-mu0)/(s/sqrt(n))
 t

#Reference statistic
alpha   <- 0.05
t.alpha <- qt(1-alpha, df=n-1)
t.alpha
```

*Do I need to consider the absolute value of t-statistic or not?*

Comment: Is this homework or a class assignment? If so, please add the `self study` tag.

Comment: @PeterFlom No it's none you guessing. It's a confusion that if i consider the absolute value of t-statistic then my null-hypothesis will be rejected . And if i don't consider the absolute value of t-statistic, then i fail to reject null-hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your alternative hypothesis is directed, i.e., $H_a : \mu > 60,000$, you have to consider the sign of the $t$ value. You obtain a negative $t$ value. Hence the mean of your data is below $60,000$. A positive $t$ value would indicate the opposite. You would consider the absolute $t$ value if your alternative hypothesis were $H_a : \mu \neq 60,000$.

Comment: While I always use a less than or greater than sign in hypothesis testing, it is worth noting that many textbooks use only an equal sign for the null, requiring the reader to infer from the alternative. I think doing it that way is stupid and lazy, but my point is that some (published) people still do it.

Comment: And how *exactly* are you both going to calculate the p value for $H_0: \mu \le 60.000$? Without resorting to Bayesian statistics, Monte Carlo methods and such? The *effective* $H_0$ *of course* is precise. That is the whole point of the Neyman-Pearson framework. And yes, it is incomplete. But it truthfully describes the hypothesis testing procedure.

Comment: @January Thanks for this comment. I agree. Technically, the p values are always based on a precise $H_0$. I removed the second part of my answer.